# Data not refreshing when using actionscript to assign dataprovider

Tags: flex4, dataprovider

My problem is when I assign the dataprovider for a spark list using actionscript it does not automatically update the list. example:

I have a list:
**< s:List id="fiterList" allowMultipleSelection="true" width="100%" height="100%"/>**

and I use actionscript to assign the dataprovider:
**filterList.dataProvider = model.ADEPTList;** (where model.ADEPTList is an ArrayCollection)

When I use an event to update model.ADEPTList the data does not show up in the list.

HOWEVER,

if I instead declare the dataprovider in the MXML like this:
**< s:List id="filterList" allowMultipleSelection="true" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{model.ADEPTList}"/>**

When the event updates model.ADEPTList it DOES show up in the list. Why is this and how can I get the list to update when assigning the dataprovider using actionscript? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because that's only an assignment, you're not binding your list's dataProvider to model.ADEPTList.

You have to read more about [flex binding mechanisms](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html). In AS3 you could use:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(filterList,"dataProvider",model,"ADEPTList");
```